# Multiple conditions AND id check

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, conditional-statements

Hi i have a mysql query with multiple conditions to check, so I'm using () to separate each one, for example:

```
WHERE (a='string' AND b='string') OR (a='otherstring' AND b='otherstring)
```

The problem I have is that I have to add a user check, si I don't know if I have to use () again, for example, is this correct?

```
WHERE ((a='string' AND b='string') OR (a='otherstring' AND b='otherstring)) AND (id='1')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot a ' on the senteces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE 
    (
        (a='string' AND b='string') 
        OR (a='otherstring' AND b='otherstring')
    ) 
    AND id='1'
```

This will find all records with an id of 1 and where a.string=b.string or a.string=otherstring.

Edit: just for extra clarification:

Basically, anything inside of brackets is equated together for example:

```
// Condition 1
(
    this=somethingelse
    and this2=somethingelse2
)
// Condition 2
and
(
    someCondition=anotherConidition
    and
    // Condition 3
    (
        thirdCondition=anotherCondition3
        or thirdCondition2=anotherCondition4
    )
)
```

in this example. both clauses in condition 1 have to be met. Condition 2 also has to be met and inside that one, `someCondition HAS to equal anotherCondition` as well as one of either of the statements in Condition 3.

Comment: @NachoNaveilhan If the answer I provided answers your question, please do Accept it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was waiting the min. time to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to your code where you did not closed your string in last condition try this

`WHERE 
    (
    (a='string' AND b='string') OR (a='otherstring' AND b='otherstring')
    )
    AND (id='1')`

Comment: yes! my question was about the double () to enclose a enclosed condition. I understand the () on id='1' is not neccesary, right?